# Pano on iPhone 6s accidentally produced a photo that changes point of view as phone is moved

Tags: panorama

I took a panoramic photo of a sun umbrella overhead and posted it on a group page in Facebook. I was just fooling around with pano, and somehow got a nearly 360 degree point of view.

I saved the photo, but though the effect is still there, can not duplicate the accidental effect in another photo.

It's as if the "still" is a video, with the camera moving, but it isn't. The viewpoint changes as you move the phone.

How could that happen? I can send you the pic, but can't attach it here.

Comment: Can you upload the image anywhere (Flickr, Instagram, anywhere that produces a URL to link to)?

Comment: Were you using the Facebook app to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have added a 360-degree panorama feature that sounds exactly like what you're describing, so I'd guess this is a Facebook feature you've discovered. More details here: 
http://newsroom.fb.com/news/2016/06/introducing-360-photos-on-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess:
In Extras, is the compass enabled for the pano?

Having heading information would make it relatively easy to lock a view to the iPhone orientation.

Maybe you stumbled upon a yet-to-be-released Artificial Reality viewing capability. : )

Answer (score 0):

you may have inadvertently used a feature of photos in ios called "live Photos.
http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/playing-and-creating-live-photos
"One of the new features in the iPhone 6s and 6s+ is the "Live Photos" feature, or as I like to call them, Harry Potter Pictures. To take one, you just have to enable the Live Photo option at the top of the camera, much like turning on flash or HDR options. After you do that, your photo will be a still photo, but it will include a low frame rate "video" of 1.5 seconds on either side of when you pressed the button for the photo. I have to put quotes around video because Apple says it is a Live Photo, not a video." 
 And from Apple. " https://www.apple.com/ios/photos/
Introducing Live Photos.

"A still photo captures an instant frozen in time. With Live Photos, you can turn those instants into unforgettable living memories. At the heart of a Live Photo is a beautiful 12‑megapixel photo. But together with that photo are the moments just before and after it was taken, captured with movement and sound.

You can bring those moments to life any time by simply pressing anywhere on the photo. You can even set your favorite Live Photo as your Lock Screen wallpaper, so you can relive a moment any time your phone leaves your pocket. And you can view Live Photos on your other Apple devices, too."

Comment: _"it will include a low frame rate "video" of 1.5 seconds on either side of when you pressed the button"_ -- I've heard of predictive technology, but how exactly does it know when 1.5 seconds _before_ you press the shutter button is?

Comment: @JimGarrison it use a buffer of the video stream and constantly throws away everything older than 1.5 seconds.  When the shutter is pressed, it writes the contents of the buffer and the next 1.5 seconds of video into the file (along with the image at the moment the shutter is pressed). Same technique used in a dashcam or a flight voice data recorder.